# Space $\mathcal{D}_K$ in Rudin - Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, topological-vector-spaces

From chapter 1 we have the following definition of space $\mathcal{D}_K$.

> If $K$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\mathcal{D}_K$ denotes the space of all $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ whose support lies in $K$.

The topology on such space is introduced by the family of seminorms

$$
p_N(f) = \max \left\{ \left| D^{\alpha} f(x) \right| : x \in K_N, \left| \alpha\right| \leq N\right\}
$$

I was wondering if $n = 1$ it is possible to prove that $\mathcal{D}_K$ is bounded w.r.t. to the topology induced by the family $\left\{ p_N \right\}$.

The family of seminorms above defines a local base

$$
V_N = \left\{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) : N p_N(f) < 1 \right\}
$$
for a locally convex space (the closure of $V_N$ is a convex set). Therefore if for each $N$ there's an $s_N > 0$ such that

$$
\mathcal{D}_K \subset t V_N \;\;, \;\; t > s_N
$$

Then the set is bounded. Defining q_N = N p_N, my attempt to prove this (assuming this is true) was to use the Minkowsky functional on $V_N$ and define $s_N$ as

$$
s_N = \sup \left\{ \mu_{V_N}(\mathcal{D}_K) \right\},
$$

where

$$
\mu_{V_N}(f) = \inf \left\{ t > 0 : t^{-1}f \in V_N \right\} = \inf \left\{ t > 0 : f \in tV_N \right\}
$$

If I can prove such $\sup$ exists I think this is all I need. I do struggle however to prove this, can anyone help me or give me a clue on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What is $K_N$?  $N{p_N}$?  I thought $N$ is a number...

Comment: $K_N$ is a sequence of compact sets such that $K_N$ lies in the interior of $K_{N+1}$. Yes, $N$ is a natural number. The sets $V_N$ are actually defined as $$V_N = \left\{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) : p_N(f) < 1/N \right\} =  \left\{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) : Np_N(f) < 1 \right\} $$, defining $q_N(f) = Np_N(f)$ I know from another theorem that $q_N$ is actually the Minkowsky functional. Hopefully I'm not messing up too much.

Comment: A bounded subspace of a Hausdorff locally convex space must be trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry? I l'm trying to prove that the subspace is bounded.

Comment: You can't. If $B$ is a bounded (linear) subspace of a topological vector space, then $B \subset \overline{\{0\}}$ (and conversely). Since $\mathcal{D}_K$ is Hausdorff, the only bounded (linear) subspace it contains is $\{0\}$.